# why calculation in bucket4j do multiply first then divide?

Tags: java

I found the code in bucket4j always do multiply first then do divide.

```
private long calculateDelayNanosAfterWillBePossibleToConsumeForGreedyBandwidth(Bandwidth bandwidth, long deficit) {
    long refillPeriodNanos = bandwidth.refillPeriodNanos;
    long refillPeriodTokens = bandwidth.refillTokens;
    long divided = multiplyExactOrReturnMaxValue(refillPeriodNanos, deficit);
    if (divided == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        // math overflow happen.
        // there is no sense to stay in integer arithmetic when having deal with so big numbers
        return (long)((double) deficit / (double)refillPeriodTokens * (double)refillPeriodNanos);
    } else {
        return divided / refillPeriodTokens;
    }
}
```

(and other part calculating tokens in class `BucketState`)

so what's the difference just doing `(long)((double) deficit / (double)refillPeriodTokens * (double)refillPeriodNanos)`?

To get more accurate? But how that could be?
Could anyone give some reason for this? I feel confused. :)

Comment: Your question is asking what is the difference between two lines of code that are the same ? Can you confirm that you are aware of "operator precedence" and that Java will execute operators depending on internal rules as opposed to the order they are typed in ?

Comment: @newbie multiply and divide are the same precedence. It's the same doing `a / c *b`  and `a * b / c`(if no overflow happen) in math.I asked why the code use the second one(use the first if overflow happen) but just use the first one.